# Out of memory in R's igraph

Tags: r, memory, igraph

I find a cocitation matrix of a large graph(200K nodes):

```
cocitation(graph)
```

Then problem occur

```
Error in cocitation(graph):At vector.pmt:125 : cannot init vector, Out of memory
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Creating a 200,000 by 200,000 matrix is a pretty big task. Try just getting the cocitation info for the vertices you are looking at (i.e. cocitation(graph,v=1)

Comment: Although people visiting this page from the future will be like "Only 200k nodes? I can run that on my toaster".

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that igraph is trying to allocate a 200K x 200K matrix to store the results. Although most of the elements in that matrix are likely to be zeros, igraph does not have a separate sparse matrix data type, so it has to allocate a chunk of memory to accomodate all the 4 x 10<sup>10</sup> elements - which is not going to work.

Since it is very likely that you don't need the whole matrix at once and you are interested in some general statistics of that matrix instead, you can simply create a for loop that goes from zero to the number of vertices minus one (since igraph indices start from zero - note that this is gonna change in 0.6 for the R interface), and calculate a single row of the cocitation matrix:

```
for (i in 0:vcount(g)-1) {
    row <- cocitation(g, v=i)
    # Do whatever you want with the row here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The general solution to out of memory problems is one of

1. Do something smart with your code so it is less memory intensive.
2. Buy a load more RAM (often cheaper than time spent faffing about).
3. Spread the load between several machines using one of the parallel
   packages.
4. Use the `bigmemory` package.
5. Use a subset of your dataset.

I agree with Ian Fellows that the last option is probably your best bet in this case.